# Python, subtract two different times in the format (HH:MM:SS - HH:MM:SS)

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I need to subtract two different times, to get the difference. For example say I have message.start and message.end, both of which are a date and time (but they are of type 'time'. I checked this using `type(message.start)` in python) and are in the following format: 'month/day/year HH:MM:SS' so for example (08/11/16 13:32:00)

In the code below I convert them to strings as I need to split up the date and time, and further split the date for other parts of the code which I don't need to show here. I tried something along message.end - message.start but that didn't work either.

I just need the time difference, so say I have 08/11/16 18:30:00 - 08/11/16 12:00:00, this should result in 6.5 or 6hrs30mins

What can I do?

This is my code:

```
startDateTime = str(message.start).split()
    startTime = startDateTime[1]
    startDate = startDateTime[0].rsplit("/")

    endDateTime = str(message.end).split()
    endTime = endDateTime[1]
    endDate = endDateTime[0].rsplit("/")
```

Comment: Hint: convert the strings to Datetime object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `strptime`method from `datetime`.

```
import datetime

format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'
startDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(message.start, format)
endDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(message.end, format)

diff = endDateTime - startDateTime
```

**output:**

```
>>> start='08/11/16 12:00:00'
>>> format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'
>>> startDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, format)
>>> end='08/11/16 18:30:00'
>>> endDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, format)
>>> diff = endDateTime - startDateTime
>>> print diff
6:30:00
```